# How to check if orientdb server is running on sudo?

Tags: python, orientdb

```
def orientdb_http_server_status():
    url = "http://{0}:{1}/server".format(settings.ORIENT_DB_CONFIG['url'], settings.ORIENT_DB_CONFIG['port'])
    request = requests.get(url,
                            auth=basic_auth)
    return request.json()
```

For now I call the above function to make sure the orient DB is up before starting my services. But the above function passes if I do not start the orientDB server without "sudo". From thereon all my API calls fail because I did not start the orientdb server with sudo command. Here is the error I get.

```
$ANSI{green {db=dinbog}} Error during file initialization for storage 'dinbog'
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/cegprakash/workspace/orientdb-community-2.2.35/databases/dinbog/dinbog.18.wal (Permission denied)
```

How do I check if the orientDB has sudo permission before starting my web service?

Answer (score -1):

You can check uid like this:

```
python -c 'import os; print os.getuid()'
213412

sudo python -c 'import os; print os.getuid()'
0
```

It will be 0 for sudo.

Comment: My requirement is not to check if my python is running on sudo. It is to check if the orientdb service is running on sudo